# How to get value of "bind:value" element?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

Is there some easy way to get value of `bind:value` element in svelte?

E.g. this is the html that I have:

```
<input type="text" name="prop" bind:value="{model.subObject.subSubObject.subSubSubProp}">
<span class="error" data-error-for="prop"></span>
```

And js that I currently have:

```
let fields : NodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-error-for]');
fields.forEach((v,k) => {
  let nameOf = v.dataset['errorFor'];
  let n = document.getElementsByName(nameOf);
  //how to get here the value of `n.value` to be `model.subObject.subSubObject.subSubSubProp`
});
```

I do not need the real bound value, but actually the object path (e.g. above it would be `model.subObject.subSubObject.subSubSubProp`).

Comment: I don't understand your question. `bind:value` is going to be transpiled, it is *not* an actual element attribute and will not appear in HTML. Therefore it cannot be queried from the rendered document.

Comment: @ThomasHennes I guessed so. Is it possible to hook in compilation phase in order to get this one?

Comment: bind value binds a value: the html input value attribute.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic Apart from writing your own parser and feeding it the svelte source files you want to analyze, I don't see how you would tackle this problem. That parser wouldn't necessarily have to be very complex, however. I think you could manage with a well-crafted regular expression.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic something like https://regex101.com/r/Mm65Bu/2 would be a start. You could write that parser in the script language of your choice (javascript, python, php, ruby, etc.).